# Input type=submit not firing when inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html and javascript are below. When the input buttons id'ed as "switch" and "next" are clicked, the handlers are not running, so the clicks are not being detected, but I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv:"Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <script text="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_home.css">

    <title> jquery home </title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container"> 
    <h1 style="position: relative; top: 10%; width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"> Learn jQuery </h1>

<div id="q_and_a_container" style="text-align: center">
    <div style="width: 200px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center" id="qa"> Nate Hill</div>

    <input type="submit" id="switch" value="See Answer" /> 
    <input type="submit" id="next" value="Next Question" />
</div>

<div id="answer_container">
    <textarea id="answer_here"> </textarea>

</div>

</div>

<div id="another_container" style="width: 300px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center">

    <h2 style="font-family: 'Chalk'">
<a href="add_question.html">Add question </a> </h2>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var question_number = 1;
    var tempText;
    var qno;

    $(document).on("click", "#switch", function(event) {

        console.log("clicked");
        if ($("#switch").val() == "See Answer") {
            tempText = $("#qa").text();
            $("#qa").text("");
            qno = "" + question_number;
            qno = "#" + qno;

            $.ajax({
                url: "answers.html",
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#qa").html($(data).filter(qno).text());
                },
                error: function(r) {
                    alert("whoops, error in ajax request");
                }
            }); // end AJAX request

            // change value
            $("#switch").val("See Question");
        } else {

            temptText = $("#qa").text();
            $("#qa").text("");
            qno = "" + question_number;
            qno = "#" + qno;

            $("#qa").text(tempText);            
            $("#switch").val("See Answer");
            }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#next", function(event) {
        question_number = question_number + 1;
        qno = "" + question_number;
        qno = "#" + qno;

        $.ajax({
            url: "questions.html",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#qa").text($(data).filter(qno).text());
            },
            error: function(r) {
                alert("whoops, error in ajax request for next question");
            }
        }); // end AJAX request
    });

    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
        // get caret position/selection
        var start = this.selectionStart;
        var end = this.selectionEnd;

        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();

        // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
        $this.val(value.substring(0, start)
                    + "\t"
                    + value.substring(end));

        // put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

        // prevent the focus lose
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});


})
```

Comment: any console errors??

Comment: Any reason why you are using submit instead of buttons? Also, why are your buttons outside of a form?

Comment: use `name` attribute in input type submit for differentiate, eg:
`<input type="submit" id="switch" name="see_answer" value="See Answer" /> 
<input type="submit" id="next" name="next_question" value="Next Question" />`

Comment: No particular reason for the submit buttons, but they haven't presented any problems on other pages.

Comment: Have you tried switching them to buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Remove any one of the below jquery library refrences. I think jquery conflict occurs.

```
<script text="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
```

Comment: the "jquery.js" is the name of the file that contains the javascript above.

Comment: @bst-for-life, Remove your jquery library refrences from head tag and paste above body tag.

Comment: what did you change? @RGS

Comment: Is it working or not? If working in fiddle, kindly review your code. Check in console.

Comment: Just commented out the stylesheet and it worked. Now I have to figure out what's wrong with the style sheet. Thanks for your help @RGS

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not adding the JS into the HTML source, you should add something like

```
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="YOUR_SRC"> </script>
```

into HTML.

Edit:
If `<script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>` is the js reference, make sure it's valid.

Comment: the "jquery.js" is the name of the file that contains the javascript above.

Comment: I also checked that it's valid and being recognized by adding an "alert" that worked.

Comment: The code works on my PC, can you check the jQuery link works for you?

Comment: @bst-for-life please check jQuery link is okay

Comment: @bst-for-life the problem shoule lie with jQuery version, check your browser is supported in jquery.com/browser-support/ or try use 1.9.x